# Ggplot2: unique() does not work properly with dplyr piping

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have some problems with the unique() function when piping with dplyr. With my simple example code this works fine:

```
category <- as.factor(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4))
quality <- as.factor(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 0, 2, 1))
mydata <- data.frame(category, quality)
```

This adjusts my dataframe so that it is easier to work with and produce a nice plot:

```
mydata2 <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(category, quality) %>% 
  mutate(count_q = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(category) %>% 
  mutate(tot_q = n(),pc = count_q*100 / tot_q) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  arrange(category)

myplot <- ggplot(mydata2, aes(x = category, y = pc, fill = quality)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(
    x = category,
    y = pc,
    label = round(pc,digits = 1),
    group = quality),
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5)) +
  ggtitle("test") +
  xlab("cat") +
  ylab("%") +
  labs("quality")

myplot
```

Looks exactly like I want:

[image]

However, with my actual data the same code produces this mess:

[image]

I did find a solution: when I add this line and use the new `mydata.unique` as the basis for my ggplot, it works exactly like with my example data. This is not needed in the example data for some reason, whereas in my actual data the `unique()` within piping seems to do nothing.

```
mydata.unique <- unique(mydata2[c("quality","category", "count_q", "tot_q", "pc")])
```

What I don't understand is why I need to add the above line. Obviously I can't share my actual data. Maybe someone still understands what this is about. Maybe it has to do with other (irrelevant) columns in the data that can't be processed by `unique()`?

Answer (score 2):

Try with `distinct()` instead of `unique()`. And in this case, probably you need to summarise instead of `mutate() + distinct()`

Answer (score 1):

If your original df has more variables, try this:

```
mydata2 <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(category, quality) %>% 
  mutate(count_q = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(category) %>% 
  mutate(tot_q = n(),pc = count_q*100 / tot_q) %>% 
  distinct(category, quality, count_q, tot_q, pc, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  arrange(category)
```

Or maybe as mentioned by @adalvarez replace `mutate` with `summarise`.